# Which US states are dry, but not hot?

Tags: weather

What are some locations in the U.S. with low humidity and a temperature that rarely rises above 75 degrees F?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Alaska? It's both cold and dry there.

Comment: @PMF Alaska is [far from dry](http://www.usa.com/rank/us--average-humidity--state-rank.htm).

Comment: @WeatherVane Relative humidity might be high (in fact, higher than I expected) but due to the cold temperatures, the absolute humidity is still low.

Comment: 75°F is around 24°C, so not exactly cold...

Comment: @TobySpeight True, but the question was about states where temperature doesn't rise above 75°F. In Alaska, it rarely rises over 60°F, which is less.

Comment: @PMF, the question just mentions "locations", rather than entire states.  That probably includes a lot more places.  I expect (most of, possibly all) Alaska qualifies, even though I've never been there.  :-)  My comment was aimed at the question, not at the other comments!

Comment: This would seem to be simply answered by looking at https://www.usairnet.com/weather/maps/current/relative-humidity/ - which was the first site I found when searching.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - I'll suggest it is more difficult than that. Particularly in the high desert areas of the Southwest, the early am humidity is as high as it is going to get, and the day/night temperature swings are more dramatic, meaning the relative humidity plummets like a rock during the day. Right now the relative humidity is 73% at 46F. By late afternoon when it hits 80F it will be under 20%.

Comment: Also, it's best to leave out "Question about" in the title, as it's a prefix that can be added to any topic. Best to provide more detail to both title and body of your question.

Comment: What do you want? The answer gave you cold states,  But is this what you want?  Your cut-off of 75 degrees F suggests that you want temperate, not cold states. And do you want states that are temperate on average, or temperate year round?  And the point about locations vs states is valid.

Comment: I'll propose Leadville CO : "Over the course of the year, the temperature typically varies from 5°F to 69°F and is rarely below -9°F or above 75°F." The 10,000 foot elevation may be an issue to some folks though. But Melanzana clothing is there...

Comment: The summit of the highest mountain in the area meets your requirements.  It's wilderness, though, you can't live there.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to quantify what is meant by "rarely rises over 75°F", but I had a look at *average* humidity and temperature for each state in USA.

The website **World Population Review** carries pages with statistics about the weather in USA.

[Coldest States 2022](https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/coldest-states) shows the 10 states with the lowest average **temperature**.

- Alaska - 28.1 °F
- North Dakota - 41.1 °F
- Minnesota - 41.8 °F
- Maine - 41.9 °F
- Wyoming - 42.3 °F
- Montana - 42.6 °F
- Vermont - 43.2 °F
- Wisconsin - 44 °F
- Idaho - 44 °F
- New Hampshire - 44.2 °F

[Least Humid States 2022](https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/least-humid-states)  shows the 10 states with the lowest average **humidity**.

- Nevada - 38.30%
- Arizona - 38.50%
- New Mexico - 45.90%
- Utah - 51.70%
- Colorado - 54.10%
- Wyoming - 57.10%
- Montana - 60.40%
- California - 61.00%
- Idaho - 62.40%
- Oklahoma - 64.00%

Three states appear in both lists, in the same order

| State | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wyoming | 42.3 °F | 57.10% |
| Montana | 42.6 °F | 60.40% |
| Idaho | 44.0 °F | 62.40% |

Comment: @JonCuster hmm... [Climate in New Mexico](https://weather.nmsu.edu/climate/about/) states: **Relative Humidity** ranges from an average of near 65 percent about sunrise to near 30 percent in midafternoon; however, afternoon humidities in warmer months are often less than 20 percent and occasionally may go as low as 4 percent.

Comment: @JonCuster it gives New Mexcio 45.9% average humidity.

Comment: Which might not be totally unreasonable, given the large temperature swings common in the high desert. Still nobody will mistake New Mexico (or Nevada, Arizona, Utah) for Florida...

Comment: very nice, and shows my intuition (and experience) of the Southwest and Mountain West being likeliest targets.

Comment: And for a weather question, you seem to be the proper person to answer...

Comment: Whether vain or not?

Comment: I'll leave that determination up to Carly Simon...

Comment: @JonCuster that song isn't about me...

Comment: and here I was thinking "I bet you think this song is about you"...

Comment: @JonCuster heh, I only thought the song might be about me *after* I chose the name ;)